# How to setup JPA Entity classes?

Tags: java, jpa

I am struggling with how to setup my JPA entity classes and which annotations should go where

I have the following tables:

```
Table Customer {
    id: primary key,
    name
}

Table CustomerDimension {
    id: primary key, foreign key(Customer.id),
    detail
}
```

Currently I have the following entity classes:

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private CustomerDimension customerDimension;
}

public class CustomerDimension {
    // ? what is meant to go here?
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "detail")
    private String detail;
}
```

What annotation is meant to go on `CustomerDimension.id` to allow me to insert a new Customer that has a new CustomerDimension?

Should `CustomerDimension` also have a reference back to `Customer`?

Comment: just put `@Id`, since you have a unidirectional relationship

Comment: @Ramanlfc - isn't it a bi-directional relationship, I can go from CustomerDimension -> Customer and vice versa?

Comment: You also need to add annotations `@Entity` and `@Table` on both classes.

Comment: for the second class you need @GeneratedValue as well, you should go through some basic tutorial to see exmaples

Comment: you've got the mapping completely opposite of what your schema requires

Answer (score 0):

```
Table Customer {
    id: primary key,
    name
}

Table CustomerDimension {
    id: primary key, 
    foreign key(Customer.id),
    detail
}
```

`CustomerDimension` is the owning side. so, the `@OneToOne` mapping should be like

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}

public class CustomerDimension {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "detail")
    private String detail;

     @OneToOne
   private Customer customer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following problems :

- Customer and CustomerDimension need the annotation `@Entity`.
- In your DDL, the table `CustomerDimension` has a foreign key on `Customer`. Hence, the `@OneToOne` relationship should be declared on `CustomerDimension`'s side.
- Still in the DDL, your foreign key does not have an explicit name. I will assume it is `customer_id` and use it to declare the `@JoinColumn` (see below)
- `@Column` annotations are required only if you need the column to have a name which is different from the attribute's name (but you can keep them for clarity).

Here is how I would map it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer") //Optional
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name") //Optional
  private String name;
}
```

And for `CustomerDimension` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerDimension") //Optional
public class CustomerDimension {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "detail") //Optional
  private String detail;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") //NOT optional
  private Customer customer
}
```

EDIT (answer to your comment) :

If you really want your FK to be the primary key, you can do it like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerDimension") //Optional
public class CustomerDimension {

  @Column(name = "detail") //Optional
  private String detail;

  @Id
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id") //NOT optional
  private Customer customer
}
```

I still wonder why you do not put all information in the same table. It would save you a SQL join.

Comment: I feel I may have given the table definitions wrong. `Customer` is the root object (the context/subject if you like). `CustomerDimension` is just extra information for `Customer`, so I am expecting to get to the `CustomerDimension` entity from the `Customer` entity. In addition, `CustomerDimension.id` is not generated. It should be the same as the referenced `Customer.id`. `Customer` is the entity that generates the id

Comment: @Cheetah then you can define the FK as a PK but it seems to be a weird use case. Edited the answer.

Comment: Its a separate table because a `CustomerDimension` record is huge and not always required.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a `OneToMany` biidirectional relationship with a foreign key instead of a join table. A join table seems to be preferred by vendors, but it's OK.

So, you have a list (or set) of `CustomerDimensions` in `Customer`, but with the `mappedBy` value set.

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    List<CustomerDimensions> dimensions;
}
```

and

```
public class CustomerDimension {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "detail")
    private String detail;

    @ManyToOne
    Customer customer;

}
```

It's natural that `Customers` have a set of dimensions. By having a `bidirectional` mapping, if you have a dimension, then you can look up the customer easy (just reference the customer field)

EDIT: Since the `CustomerDimension` table has a `Customer` id reference, you can select many `CustomerDimensions` for one `Customer`, hence a `OneToMany` relationship. In order to set the `CustomerDimension.customer_id` field, simply put a `CustomerDimension` in the `Customers` list of dimensions.

Comment: It's actually a one-to-one mapping, so a Customer only has one dimension. But it is bidirectional, but what I don't understand is that there is no annotation on `CustomerDimension.id`...how does this value get populated?

Comment: What makes you think it's OnToOne? You need the typical ID annotations on CustomerDimension.id. I left them out because you did. See edits.